# How can I add clock on my VB2010 form?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I wanted to add clock to my form in VB2010. This is what I've tried but it isn't working:
I added `Timer` control on the form, added `Label` and add this code on the `Timer`

```
Label1.Text = TimeOfDay
```

Comment: Can you add more code and an error message?

Comment: try: `Label1.Text = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.ToString()`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how can I add clock on visual basic form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34796917/how-can-i-add-clock-on-visual-basic-form)